# How to hold value for borrowed cash used to fund school tuition

Tags: united-states, investing, loans, student-loan, tuition

I need to pay for the tuition for a 2-year graduate school program.

Since I don't have to, and can't, pay tuition of 2 years in advance, but need to pay interest, I want hold the value of my borrowed cash against the interest. I don't want to waste the interest. Is there any low risk assets with annual return that at least I can cover the loan interest?

The setting is like:
Let's say I plan to borrow 150k USD to fund my tuition and other living expenses, and the tuition will be charged 4 times in September and January in 1st and 2nd year respectively. And let's say the annual interest rate is 1.7% with 3 years of grace period where I need to pay only the interest.

How should I do to hold value for my borrowed cash?

Comment: Why would you not borrow each lump as and when you need it?

Comment: It's a special loan with a low interest rate. But it requires to borrow in bulk.

Comment: What program are you enrolled in that doesn't pay a stipend *and* prevents you from working at least part-time?

Comment: at 1.7% APR, your interest charges through the grace period will be $7,650, $212.50 per month for 36 months. Are you sure taking this lump at that rate is actually less expensive than just taking a loan at the prevailing rate when you actually need it?

Comment: @chepner 2 years probably rules out a Ph.D so any professional program (law, medicine), MBAs, most non-STEM degrees, many master's programs even in STEM fields

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is basically borrow money to invest. This is generally a bad idea. It's called leveraging risk and it can work to your advantage, until it doesn't.

If this is a special loan with a low interest rate then I'm going to assume it's a family member? That's also generally a bad idea because it can affect your relationship with them.

As I understand it (and I could be wrong) a federally backed student loan doesn't accrue interest while you're in school. So you might be better off taking a federal student loan and then take this special loan for the lower interest and pay off the federal loans.

But lets take even another step back. $150,000 seems like a lot to me. If it's a private school, stop. You want to go to your local state university. Mine estimates around $80,000 for someone from out of state and $46,000 if your in state. http://admissions.utah.edu/cost/

What's your local state university cost? I would look at that before considering going into debt of $150,000. You can buy a house for that much money.